# App restarts after showing Admob interestial

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have an App which was using the old ADMOB SDK. I have started using the Google play services  library for showing the ADMOB interestial ad. I have an Ad every time the Activity starts.

ISSUE:
In some Phones I could see the Activity restarts after every close of the AD. Because of this I could see only the Ads. Also I found that the activity reaches onDestroy(). Is there is any way to avod it ?

Kindly help me to resolve this

Android Manifest

```
 <supports-screens            
 android:xlargeScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" />   

<!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/memorygamefreelogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
               android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 

     <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
    <activity  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Splash"
        android:label="Memory Game" 
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.splash.MemoryHome"
        android:label="memorygame" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.memorygame.free.MEMORYHOME" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.splash.MemoryGame"
        android:label="memorygame" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.memorygame.free.MEMORYGAME" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show an interstitial ad a new (InterstitialAd) Activity is started. This means that your current Activity will no longer be visible and Activity#onStop will be called.

The Android framework **may** also decide to remove your Activity from memory altogether. If it does so, it **may** call Activity#onDestroy. This explains the differences you see between some of your phones. I'm not aware of any way to influence this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        showAd();
    }
}
```

Like this, the Ad shows only on fresh start.